# What is the difference between active notifications and push notifications?

Tags: notifications, active-sync, push-notifications

I know what push notifications are. But recently, I saw the term active notifications and push notifications used interchangeably. I am confused if they mean the same thing or different things. Does active notifications means real time notifications?

Comment: Where did you see it?  Link at least one source.

Comment: Googling for "android active notification" returned [this article](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2142061/how-to-fake-the-moto-xs-active-notifications-on-your-android-phone.html) as exact keyword, which seems to be lockscreen notification. Other results are related to Moto X's active display notification/dynamic notification... so, please clarify if this is what you meant.

Comment: Yup. saw that article. I want to know if it is more than that. Does active notification mean real time notification?